# Domain Driven Design: Defining the domain and subdomains of the business

Tags: domain-driven-design

I am having problems finding the right granularity to define the domain, subdomains and bounded contexts for my models.

In the domain of a tool manufacturer, the core domain could be "production", the subdomains "Sales", "Finance",
"spare parts" and "dealer management". The dealer management system could be a bounded context within subdomain "dealer management"

But in the project, developing the dealer management system, "dealer management" is defined as business domain.
The core domain here is "retailer network", subdomains:"contract management", "activities" and "retailer care". 
A bounded context in the core domain "retailer network" is "dealer site" and "geography".

In my example the subdomain (retailer management) of the overall business is also defined as domain and parted into subdomains.

Is this correct and defining the domain is a question of perspective or am I wrong with the concepts?

Comment: I think you are right. However just make sure you do not overly segregate your bounded contexts. Micro-service architectures also have their flaws.

Comment: Finding context boundaries is the most non-trivial in DDD. It requires extensive knowledge crunching process, working together with domain experts for a while, identifying their needs, finding the language and the context for that language. It is *impossible* to answer you "right" or "wrong" based on a 100 words question. Even more, it would be irresponsible.

Answer (score 6):

As commenter @AlexeyZimarev pointed out correctly, whether your definitions of domain and boundaries are correct depends entirely on understanding the business. Which we can't really do here.

However, I would like to offer a technical crutch that helped me at least to create *bounded contexts* (==microservices). This is:

**A bounded context must not require synchronous communication with other contexts in order to execute its business logic.**

And I don't just mean synchronous in technology. If there is an asynchronous messaging system between contexts, but the context has to wait for an answer, that is still synchronous.

A bounded context should still work if all other contexts are removed (services are stopped).

I think this is the hard part, then grouping them to domains, deciding which is the core domain, which are supporting ones, etc. is not a technical task.

Note: Without knowing your case, "dealer management" and "contract management" are typically things that are *bad* candidates for bounded contexts. If other contexts need to work with "contracts" or "dealers", that will usually be synchronous communication. They need to "get" a contract, then do something with it. This means the context is not really bounded.